# PHP if else issue occured

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't get this if else. Why i am getting "Yes"

Here is my code

```
<?php 
$id ='8000009E-1656394540';
if($id == 0){
    echo "Yes";
}else {
    echo "No";
    
}
?>
```